# "if" condition problem in java Armstrong code

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote the armstrong number question in java by myself(sorry if its silly, I'm new to programming).
The "result is supposed to give 1 value when i enter a coorect armstrong number but it gives 0,why?

Code-

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int result = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            while (n > 0) {
                i = n % 10;
                sum += i * i * i;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            if (sum == n) {
                System.out.print("1");
            } else {
                System.out.print("0");
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to take a look at [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you're still stuck, make sure you ask a specific question and provide everything we would need to answer it (like what *"the armstrong number question in java"* is).

Comment: After loop what is the value of `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n is changed in the while loop. After the while loop `n == 0` (if n was entered as a non-negative number). This the only case where `sum == n` is true will be `sum == 0`. You need to introduce a temporary variable which is modified in the loop and keep n unchanged.

```
int temp = n;
while (temp > 0) {
  int i = temp % 10;
  sum += i * i * i;
  temp /= 10;
}
```

N.B. result is not used, i not decalred inside the while loop

Comment: Thank you soo much. It was a silly mistake anyway very cool explanation.